# svn check-in failed because subfolder is missing. is there alternative to checking out fresh repository?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I would like to check a particular folder ("myfolder") into SVN.
TortoiseSVN believes it should contain a subfolder "mysub", but that subfolder no longer exists.  (Long ago, I may have screwed something up when I renamed "mysub" to something else.)

TortoiseSVN shows the text-status of "mysub" as "deleted".
When I try to check "myfolder" into SVN, I get this error:

> Error.  Commit failed.  Entry for '...\mysub' has no url.  Try a
>   'Cleanup'.  If that doesn't work, you need to do a fresh checkout.

Cleanup completed successfully, but did not solve the problem.

First question:  Are they saying I should delete my local copy of "myfolder" and replace it with a newly checked-out copy?  (Sorry for the newbie question, but I am new to SVN and want to make sure I don't do anything stupid.)

Second question:  Can anyone suggest an alternative?  There are hundreds, maybe thousands, of files and folders under "myfolder" that have not yet been checked into SVN.  I would lose all these files and folders if I deleted my working version.  I could manually merge these files/folders into a newly checked-out repository, but that would be an enormous pain.  I R-E-A-L-L-Y hope there is a way to fix the problem without deleting my working repository.

Comment: try cleanup, update, then commit then add the new folder to svn

Comment: Not the best workaround, but will it commit if you create the mysub folder?

Comment: @Karl:  I tried what you suggest, but that didn't work.  Windows explorer displays a yellow exclamation point on both 'myfolder' and 'mysub'.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to run:

`svn cleanup`

`svn update`

and then try your commit.  If it doesn't work, does it fail in the same manner? what is the output of

`svn status`

What version of svn are you running?  file/directory moves got significantly more fancy in 1.6.

Comment: DOH. I just noticed that scibuff already said the same thing and that it worked.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check in a folder or a file which does not exist on the latest version on the repository you need to tell the svn that this is a newly added thing, this can be done by right click on file/folder using eclipse svn plugin then choosing add to version control, or similler methods using tortoise svn or any other svn clients.